# How to subtract multiple times from a total and show the remainder of each calculation in PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say $total=1000 and I need to subtract $a=100, $b=50, $c=10, $d=50 from $total and show the remainder each time. I would like to see:

```
$total-$a=$new_total //900
$new_total-$b=$new_total //850
$new_total-$c=$new_total //840
$new_total-$d=$new_total //790
```

The first line is easy but after that I'm lost. The subtracted numbers are comming from a form so I don't know how many there will be. Could be $a-$t or just $a. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: you can take all input values in a array .give name of fields like name="val[field]" and then you can use foreach loop and add all fields into a variable and then substract that number with $total

Comment: can you show your full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap your assignment around and echo the result each time:

```
echo PHP_EOL, $total = 1000;

echo PHP_EOL, $new_total = $total-$a; //900
echo PHP_EOL, $new_total = $new_total-$b; //850
echo PHP_EOL, $new_total = $new_total-$c; //840
echo PHP_EOL, $new_total = $new_total-$d; //790
```

[Example](https://eval.in/)

Sounds like the number of these variables is dynamic. The easiest way to implement something like this with a variable number of inputs is to use an array in the frontend and loop it in the back:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) : ?>
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then:

```
echo PHP_EOL, $total = 1000;
foreach ($_POST['numbers'] as $number) {
    echo PHP_EOL, $total -= $number;
}
```

[Example](https://eval.in/537843)

Comment: That sounds perfect, Thank you.

Comment: If my input looks like this: <input type="hidden" name="numbers[]" value="<?php echo $totfee; ?>"> do I still need the <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) : ?> and <?php endif; ?>

Comment: The values is a looped string: $totfee .= ($fee * $qty);

Comment: The for loop was just an example